# Prediction error in R in case of new levels for variable

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I'm using the GBM package for prediction in R. Traning works pretty well with a reasonable
error rate, however, when wanted to run the prediction on a training set that contains factor variable with new levels then I got the following error:

```
gbm1 <- gbm(SalePrice ~., data=bb,distribution="gaussian",n.trees=7000,cv.folds=3,shrinkage=0.001,interaction.depth=4)

    f.predict <- exp(predict.gbm(gbm1,data.frame(bbv),n.trees=7000))
        Error in predict.gbm(gbm1, data.frame(bbv), n.trees = 7000) : 
          New levels for variable <and the name of the levels are listed>
```

Tried to search on the error text but only found the GBM code itself ;(

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: The error is clear ( even you cut it before giving us the name of the variable, I don't know why ), you have a new level in the the new data  you give to `gbm.predict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the GBM package, but the error suggest that GBM cannot deal with predicting from a model when the prediction data contains a previously unknown level. The rationale behind it is that the model can only say something about the class of data that it was trained for. In the case of a simple linear model, you cannot expect the model `a~b` (`a` depends on `b`) to predict data which involves a new variable b, i.e. `a~b+c`. The model has no trained behavior for `b+c`, only for for `b`.